# how to deploy a vert.x verticle at runtime?

Tags: java, vert.x

my project is generated by http://start.vertx.io

my http handler:

```
// ...
public void handle(RoutingContext ctx) {
  String verticleName = ctx.queryParams().get("v");
  ctx.vertx().deployVerticle(verticleName);
  ctx.response().end();
}
// ...
```

but it reports error

```
java.lang.RuntimeException: Resource not found: verticles/TestVerticle.java
        at io.vertx.core.impl.verticle.CompilingClassLoader.<init>(CompilingClassLoader.java:68)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.JavaVerticleFactory.createVerticle(JavaVerticleFactory.java:37)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VerticleManager.doDeployVerticle(VerticleManager.java:217)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VerticleManager.doDeployVerticle(VerticleManager.java:193)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VerticleManager.doDeployVerticle(VerticleManager.java:180)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VerticleManager.deployVerticle(VerticleManager.java:156)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:623)
        at io.vertx.core.impl.VertxImpl.deployVerticle(VertxImpl.java:608)
```

Comment: The answer below is correct. I would just like to point out that deploying a verticle based on user input is very dangerous, and you should never do it ‍♂️

Answer (score 1):

By default the verticle name should be a fully-qulified class name that has a no-args constructor and implements Verticle (or extends one of its implementors). e.g.

```java
package demo;

import io.vertx.core.AbstractVerticle;

public class MyVerticle extends AbstractVerticle {
    @Override
    public void start() throws Exception {
        // ...
    }
}
```

Then you can do:

```java
vertx.deployVerticle("demo.MyVerticle");
```

If you want to use another mechanism you can create a custom `VerticleFactory` (https://vertx.io/docs/vertx-service-factory/java/) and use your own logic. e.g.

```java
package demo;

import io.vertx.core.Promise;
import io.vertx.core.Verticle;
import io.vertx.core.spi.VerticleFactory;

import java.util.concurrent.Callable;

public class CustomVerticleFactory implements VerticleFactory {
    @Override
    public String prefix() {
        return "custom";
    }

    @Override
    public void createVerticle(String verticleName, ClassLoader classLoader, Promise<Callable<Verticle>> promise) {
        if (verticleName.equals("custom:x")) {
            promise.complete(() -> new MyVerticle());
        } else {
            promise.fail("...");
        }
    }
}
```

Load it to your Vertx instance:

```java
vertx.registerVerticleFactory(new CustomVerticleFactory());
```

And then you can do:

```
vertx.deployVerticle("custom:x");
```

Answer (score 0):

Found the right way.
I should start the app with `-Xbootclasspath/a:.`
Then the class loader can found java source files(XXXVerticle.java) at `.` (working dir)